# Attach debugger to a process without creating a new thread

Tags: c, multithreading, debugging, winapi, reverse-engineering

I want to attach a debugger to another process but I need to attach the debugger without creating a new thread. Usually, when a debugger is attached to a process it creates a new thread within the target process and executes a routine called `ntdll!DbgBreakPoint` within the created thread.

This routine executes the `int3` instruction which allows the debugger to take control of the execution so when the debugger kicks in, this is how the call stack looks like right after attaching the debugger:

```
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x39
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

The reason why I need to attach a debugger under those restrictions is because I need to debug the creation of new threads in ntdll and debugging it after threads were already created doesn't make any sense.

Because I have control of the target program, I can set the main thread's context's program counter to whatever value I want and therefore I can set the first executed instruction to be `int 3` somewhere in the code but I can't catch the exception because when I attach a debugger there are already threads created and I get back to the same problem.

I have already tried to address my problem using weird WinDbg/ollydbg/x64dbg settings but I couldn't make it work. So to my point, is there any debugger / debugging method that can allow me to attach to a remote process without creating a remote thread and catch my `int 3`?

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: yes, exist :) absolute not need create new thread on attach

Comment: @RbMm, Hi, can you elaborate please?

Comment: for start debug already running process - all what we need - call ZwDebugActiveProcess api, create remote thread in debugee (DbgUiRemoteBreakin) absolute not need, i dont know for what reason this done. i have own written private debugger, one is the best from all existing. but this is only my on this moment

Comment: @RbMm, you are right, I see that `NtDebugActiveProcess` and `RtlpCreateUserThreadEx` are called separately, but do you know about any debugger that does only the `NtDebugActiveProcess` call?

Comment: yes, absolute separately - exist api DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakIn - you can not it in your debugger :)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PiIZeQJ.png

Comment: DbgEng.dll after calling NtDebugActiveProcess call DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakIn which create remote thread - DbgUiRemoteBreakin. you in as case can nop (insert ret at begin) this function. in my own debugger i not call it

Comment: I'm confused, if you want the debugger attached before your application starts creating threads, why not just launch the process _from the debugger_?

Comment: @theB, simply because I have to attach to an existing process, thats the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution,

There is an option in WinDbg called "Non-invasive debugging". Using this option the debugger will not attempt to create a new thread within the target process.

To enable it, when attaching to a new process just check this box:

[image]

And you are good to go!

Thanks to RbMm for clarifying this issue!

**-- EDIT --**

This solution do let you view the code and registers but It doesn't break the debugger on `int 3` instructions and therefore it is not a good solution.

Comment: but are this is real debugging ?"The process can be examined but debug events will not be received" - i also have this option in self debugger9atach without debug and suspend!)

Comment: what you found - is not a debugging and solution for you

Comment: is your solution breaks on `int 3`?

Comment: not understand your question. are my debugger breaks on int 3 ?

Comment: Yes. Do you catch the debug exceptions?

Comment: of course. strange question. as local debugger my product is better then WinDbg/ollydbg/x64dbg. and my debugger can not only break on int 3 but and select not break on status_breakpoint/single_step on first chance. very power options

Comment: @RbMm is your debugger public?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116942/discussion-between-rbmm-and-aviv).

Comment: as solution you can run 2 instance of WinDbg(or OllyDbg) and in second instance 'nop'(insert ret at begin) DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakIn in first. than use it for debugging